# Filtering conditional in WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server, where-clause

I have the `PEN_TIPO` column of a table, this column can have values 0 and 2, and in the report depending on the filter I apply the condition as follows:

```
declare @PEN_TIPO int = 0

(A.PEN_TIPO = @PEN_TIPO OR @PEN_TIPO = 0)
```

However, it will have a condition that I do not need to filter this field, ie I have to get 0 and 2 from the `PEN_TIPO` column.

How can I apply this filter?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Can you add sample data?

Comment: Your declared variable name doesn't match the variable you use. Also @PEN_TIPO = 1 will match anything in the database - is that what you meant?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [tour].

Comment: Can you show us the whole query you're using, expected output, and current output, noting any errors you're getting?

Comment: @DaleBurrell I wrote wrong, I already corrected ..
The issue is that at some point I need the filter for PEN_TIPO not applied, now I can not do this, or it is 0 or 2 but I need it to be nullo to bring everything from PEN_TIPO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're describing, what is commonly referred to as an optional parameter.
If the user enters a parameter value, they want to filter based on that, if not, ignore it altogether.

It would typically look something like this:

```
DECLARE @PEN_TIPO INT;

(A.PEN_TIPO = @PEN_TIPO OR @PEN_TIPO IS NULL)
OPTION(RECOMPILE);
```

Please note that I added "OPTION(RECOMPILE)" to the end of the query. 
You'll want to add this to you query too, so that the optimizer can create an optimized plan based on the chosen parameter value.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually handled with a similar conditional where clause using `NULL`, but you code would if you defaulted the value to 1 or another value.

In the below proc, we default the parameter to `NULL`. It will remain `NULL` if your report / application doesn't pass in a value.

- If it remains null, all rows are returned.
- If a value is passed in that is 0 or 2, the filter is applied.
- If a value is passed in that isn't 0 or 2, an error is raised.

Here's the proc.

```
create proc myProc (@PEN_TIPO int = NULL)
as

if (@PEN_TIPO IS NOT NULL) or (@PEN_TIPO NOT IN (0,2))
begin
    raiserror('Invalid parameter',16,1)
end

SELECT A.*
FROM SomeTable A
WHERE (A.PEN_TIPO = @PEN_TIPO OR @PEN_TIPO IS NULL)
```

[Aaron Bertrand has an in-depth post on these](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example/) *Kitchen Sink* type queries.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do this ?

```
DECLARE @PEN_TIPO INT = NULL 
SELECT *
FROM TableName 
WHERE 
    A.PEN_TIPO = ISNULL(@PEN_TIPO, PEN_TIPO)
```

When `@PEN_TIPO = NULL` then `A.PEN_TIPO = A.PEN_TIPO` which will bring everything.